# What is the proper reaction to a post which clearly lacks research?

Tags: discussion

On e.g. [this review](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/790477) the post is clearly very low quality and as already stated in the comments the OP shows absolutely no research or attempt to solve the question on his own.

Since it doesn't look ok to me but neither is off topic, spam, too broad nor opinion based the closest option to me seemed to flag it as duplicate (what I did) but wouldn't it be better to have another flag like "This could have been easily resolved in 3 seconds doing some research"?

First recommend way to go seems to be a simple downvote but that's not an option given in the review.

Answer (score 24):

Not really. Flags are to let moderators know about things that require their intervention and we can't do anything about this. We could delete, but that doesn't seem appropriate.

So do what you did, vote to close/flag as a duplicate or simply downvote. Note that the reasons given for downvoting, seen when you hover over the downvote button, are (emphasis mine):

> **This question does not show any research effort;** it is unclear or not useful

So, the correct action here is to downvote. Sadly, that is not one of the options you are given in the review queue though.

Comment: I don't like this suggestion although I read it all the time. I think people spending effort in SE sites by writing decent answers and even doing research to answer ignoramuses's questions should have an option to mark a post as not only _"Oh, I'm sorry to tell you, but this is not well written and not helpful"_ but to mark it as _"WTF!? Have you even considered to google in the first place?"_

Comment: @perlduck in that case, this might not be the best site for you. What you suggest is needlessly confrontational, rude and unwelcoming. Just downvote and move on.

Comment: Well, I believe this site _is_ perfect for me and downvoting or VTC is usually what I do in the cases mentioned. On the other hand I also consider it rude by askers to simply dump their requirements and wait for an answer that they then copy'n'paste in their code. 
It was that kind of questions I had in mind when I wrote my above comment. Probably it applies more to SO (where I come from) than to AU. One SO there are far more questions like _"gimme ze codez, QUICK, i must complete assignment 2morrow"_. Those make me feel upset.

Comment: @PerlDuck I understand, and I know the feeling. Nevertheless, this site (and every other SE site, including SO, believe it or not) expects and requires users to be civil at all times. So if all you can say is something like *"WTF!? Have you even considered to google in the first place?"* then just say nothing at all. Downvote and move on.

Comment: Yes. I usually ask the typical questions (what have you tried? show code, an mcve, etc.) over there then and then move on. But it's just not fair that they can be as shameless as they want and we have to behave like Mother Teresa. – So be it. Peace.

Comment: @PerlDuck I know, and no it isn't fair. I'm not saying you're wrong, and I know *exactly* how you feel, but as a mod, I need to make these things clear :)

Comment: … and I think I know how _you_ feel. ;-)